# My report is not displaying the .00 in the Current Amount totals.

Tags: crystal-reports, report

My report is not displaying the .00 in the Current Amount totals. Shows $2,355,857 and not $2,355,857.00 any suggestions? Thank you in advance my friends.

Comment: What's the date type?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Increase Decimals" button, located on the toolbar.

[image: Increase Decimals]

Comment: Hey Craig, tried that one first. Seems like there is some sort of filter blocking it.